# HTTP Streaming without an audio only stream

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, stream, streaming

I am creating a video streaming app and i have so far adhered to [Apples Live Streaming guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
The Problem that i am facing is that based on this extract

**NOTE:** This is not a live streaming app but more of a VOD app with prerecorded content

> Provide a 64 Kbps stream
>   If your app uses HTTP Live Streaming over cellular networks, you are required to provide at least one stream at 64 Kbps or lower bandwidth (the low-bandwidth stream may be audio-only, or audio with a still image).
>
> Important: When you submit your app to the App Store you should specify a url to your cellular 64 Kbps stream so the app reviewers can test it. Otherwise, the reviewers will need to sniff the network packets coming from your app to try and locate the stream. If your stream does not have a measured bit rate of less than or equal to 64 Kbps, your app will be rejected.

Apple requires you to create a stream that is 64Kbps which implies an audio only stream
This becomes an issue when the content is very video sensitive
Basically what i would like is to do away with the audio only stream if possible
But apple's guidelines clearly do not allow this ..

I have also confirmed this with a colleague of mine who had a similar VOD type app rejected for similar reasons

> May 30, 2012 02:23 PM. From Apple.
>   9.4
>
> We found that your HTTP Live Streaming implementation did not include a 64 kbps stream, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.

I would have accepeted this as my bitter fate ...
However on testing certain other streaming services like Vevo and Vimeo even after using the network link conditioner to simulate really bad network conditions, i failed to chance upon this audio only stream *scratches head

**UPDATE :**
Vimeo apparently offers offline playback does that mean they have implemented a custom streaming algorithm ?
Is this possible ?

**To summarize :**
Am i missing something here ?
Is it possible to replicate that behavior ?
Also on some reading Vimeo does only 720 and 1080 (Still confirming this) .. Is this possible ?
Is there work around the audio only stream ?